# Can I access an IP Camera PTZ port through socket programming in Python and send hex bytes to it?

Tags: python

Hello and sorry for this basic question since I am new to programming.

I have a Sony FCB IP camera that works on Visca protocol. I tried socket programming in python to send visca commands but had no idea what i was doing.

I need to access the ptz port of my IP camera and start sending visca commands to it through my python code. How can I establish a connection between local system and the camera and ensure that commands are sent through TCP protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask for the .dll/.so from OEM, in case you are stuck. ;)